# Response and predictor must be vectors of the same length

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, decision-tree

I'm using pROC curve in order to compare the performance of models. 
I have plotted four SVM models. Now when I plot Decision tree model I get the following error:

```
Error in roc.default(x, predictor, ...) : 
  Response and predictor must be vectors of the same length.
```

The following code represent how i plotted the curve:

```
rocobj1 <-plot(roc(as.numeric(video.test$rate),as.numeric(svm.grossesse.pred4)),main="Comparaison ",col="#1c61b6")
rocobj5 <-lines.roc(as.numeric(video.test$rate),as.numeric(predArbreDecision),col="pink")
```

Comment: Try `plot(1:3, 1:2)`.

Comment: I wouldn't like to plot numerical value because I already build a model based on decision tree. And I like to see its performance through pROC curve

Comment: Sorry, that comment was meant to clarify the error message. If you run it, you will get similar error, `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Comment: Thanks I understood the reason